# Monolog logs file for every session

Tags: symfony, monolog

I'm using symfony for a cron run application that runs every day

I want to use monolog to write an `info` report that I can then email, so I'm looking for a way to separate the files by session id. Example:

```
report:
 type:   stream
 path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%-%sessionid%.log"
 level:  info
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Each time your cron runs, does it create a new Symfony application ?

Comment: yes the cron runs a new instance of symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `AppKernel`:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    protected $sessionId;

    public function __construct($environment, $debug, $sessionId)
    {
        $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

        parent::_construct($environment, $debug);
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @see \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::getKernelParameters()
     */
    protected function getKernelParameters()
    {
        $parameters = parent::getKernelParameters();

        // Adding session_id parameter
        $parameters['kernel.session_id'] = $this->sessionId;

        return $parameters;
    }

 /**
  * Your function here [...]
  **
}
```

Now you can use `%kernel.session_id%` in your config.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        report:
            type:  stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%-%kernel.session_id%.log"
            level:  info
```

And in your `app.php`:

```
$sessionId = '123';
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false, $sessionId);
```

You just have to pass `$sessionId` as an argument of your script