# How to create channel name for monolog in controller in symfony3

Tags: symfony, monolog

I need to have separate log files. These files should be named during code working.
It is possible? Or is there another solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions on this site. Your question is rather broad, and includes no indication of what you have tried already. This site is intended to answer specific questions, or help with specific problems, perhaps try googling general questions like this, and if you have already then let us know what you have already looked at and tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Custom Monolog Handler.

1-) You can change channel name. Write lines to config.yml

```
monolog:
    channels: [custom_channel]   # channel
    handlers:
        custom:   
            type: service   
            channels: [custom_channel]
            id: custom.handler   # service name at services.yml
```

2-) Add services.yml

```
custom.handler:
    class: AppBundle\Service\CustomHandler
    arguments: [""]
```

3-) Create Custom Handler Service

```
class Custom Handler extends AbstractProcessingHandler {


    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function write (array $record) {
        dump($record); die;
    }

}
```

4-) You can use this handler.

```
$this->get('monolog.logger.custom_channel')->info('It is info log.');

$this->get('monolog.logger.custom_channel')->alert('ALERT!', array('http://mertblog.net'));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But your example doesn't have ability to change channel name when we start to use handler. And additional service not required for this example at my opinion.

Comment: Monolog has $this->container->get('monolog.handler.handler_name')->getUrl(); .
Is there somethig like $this->container->get('monolog.handler.handler_name')->setUrl('new_url'); ?

Comment: what is your purpose wtih url? monolog do log for your messages. sample; `$this->get('monolog.logger.custom_channel')->info('It is info log.');`or error or alert

Comment: Url contains destination path for log file. I want to have an ability to change this path/name. Something like that 
$user = 'name1';
$this->container->get('monolog.handler.handler_name')->setUr‌​l($user . '.log');

Comment: No, you change to your config.yml file. If you look here https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html under 'Handlers: Writing Logs to different Locations' title, you will see it.

Comment: I looked  this documentation of course. Unfortunately symfony has no way to do it natively. But I found just now [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630818/monolog-logs-file-for-every-session) . I think I can try to use this idea.